# How to write code to MS Word using python retaining the formatting?

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to create a MS word document which compiles a lot of my existing codes ( in MATLAB and Python). I was writing it using python-docx.

If I do something like:

```
file = open('task1.m', 'r')
document.add_paragraph(file)
```

Then the code gets written in MS word in simple text format without the formatting.

Is there some way I can write the code while retaining the programming language formatting? (Keeping the colors intact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .m file doesn't contain color information. That's added by whatever IDE / editor you're using.

If you know (or can find out) how to insert html-formatted or rtf-formatted text into your word document, check out the [pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/) module.

I'm not sure how you can write this rtf-formatted text into a word document. However, if you write it out to an RTF document, this can be opened and saved by Word.

So let's say I run this code `toword.py`:

```
from docx import Document

from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import RtfFormatter

with open("toword.py", "r") as f:
    code = f.read()
    
ht = highlight(code, PythonLexer(), RtfFormatter())

with open("rtffile.rtf", "w") as wf:
    wf.write(ht)
    
doc = Document()
paragraph = doc.add_paragraph(ht)
doc.save("code.docx")
```

There's also a `pygments.lexers.matlab.MatlabLexer` form Matlab files. Or you could use `pygments.lexers.get_lexer_for_filename(filename)` to get a lexer from the filename.

Opening `rtffile.rtf` in Word:

[image]

Opening `code.docx` in Word:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`pandoc`](https://pypi.org/project/pyandoc/) module along with its [backend](https://pandoc.org/installing.html). It can convert to the docx format if you supply it some markdown, and can automatically highlight based if the markdown contains code fences.

So with this code:

``````
# from docx import Document

from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

import pandoc

with open("toword.py", "r") as f:
    code = f.read()

md = f"`````python\n{code}\n`````";
doc = pandoc.Document()
doc.markdown = bytearray(md, encoding="utf-8")
doc.add_argument("out=code.docx")
doc.docx
``````

we get the following `code.docx`:

[image]

You can play with the highlight style using the `--highlight-style=...` argument. More info [here](https://pandoc.org/demos.html)

Comment: This works like a charm for code.
But can I use it to make an entire word document? (Adding headings, images, etc)

Comment: I haven't tried, but take a look at the [markdown syntax](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/). You can include headings and images. Presumably pandoc should be fine with those.

Comment: I added a simple example of this on [github](https://gist.github.com/RAraghavarora/d29ba2cb786a8e3fc34f483f142babde) in case anyone needs.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty way to achieve this, NotePad++ has a feature where you can turn on syntax highlighting for your language. Then, select the code, right-click and select "Plugin Commands > Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting".
Now, you can paste that into Word and the colors remain.